# Database structure, primary and foreign keys

Tags: database, database-design

The whole idea is to make a website to rate teachers from all the cities and schools over the country. When the user enters the website he will have one option to choose the city. After the city is chosen the user has an opportunity to choose a school avialable in that city. When the school is chosen then the list of teachers should appear.

I want to make tables of cities, schools and teachers. 
Cities would have city name and CID as a primary key.
Schools should have School name SID as a primary key and CID as a foreign key.
And finally the Teachers table will have the name of the teacher, teacher's id CID and SID as a foreign key.

So my question is: Is it possible for the school to have an id from 1 to something in a chosen city? Or is it referencing a list of ids of all schools, and lots of id's cities independent from each other as I have drawn in the picture?

[image]

Is it propertly thougt of me?
Did I design it correctly as I described?

Comment: Can you insert your picture, instead of link to an external site?

Comment: I am sorry I dont have enough reputation to do that.

Comment: oh..ok. No worries. I posted an answer with some pointers... hope that helps. Good luck!

Comment: what if there are cities with the same name in more than one state?  Could they pick the state first, then the city?

Comment: It is not so complicated, not China or Usa:))

Comment: There is seldom good reason to force people to enter info in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final part of your question is a little confusing, if you could post your sample model here, it would be helpful. However, you seem to be on the right track. The "course" table/entity seems to be missing from your model as of now.

Instead of user actions on the website, think of the different/unique logical things here.

```
1) City   (or location) - city_id (pk), city_name...
2) School               - school_id(pk), city_id(fk), school_name...
3) Teacher              - teacher_id(pk), school_id(fk), teacher details..
4) Course               - course_id(pk), teacher_id(fk), school_id (fk)
```

There are a few other things to consider before you decide on this model though.

1) Is it possible for a school to have branches in different cities? If so, you should have a school_city_association table that has the many-to-many relationship between school and branches.

2) similar case with course - Can a course have more than one instructor, in which case you would have a new table that has the many to many associations.

3) Same goes for school and teacher - Can a teacher be associated with more than one school? What if a teacher teaches at school x this year and school y next year? If this relationship is only through a specific course and school year, they probably belong in the course table.

Comment: I am sorry if i didn't make my self clear. It was pretty clear until i draw the table, and i thought that every school should have their own id in every city. Example: Let's say there is 10 schools in every city. All the schools in New York should have id from 1 to 10. And all the schools in Chicago should have id from 1 to 10. It probably does not work this way, but somehow i got confused. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: There is nothing wrong per se with having a unique id per some other property. (Most SQL DBMSs don't make that easy to do though.) Although here an id per city is not a natural way of characterizing a school. Whichever meaning(s) of "school" applies: eg this answer shows there might be two distinct concepts needing two distinct words/phrases: school organization & school branch.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to have each school with a unique ID. There are several advantages:

- The id field can be system generated. If you duplicate school id values for each city, you have to manually search for the last value used for a particular city in order to create a new school in that city.
- Foreign keys to a school needs only one field, the school id. Otherwise, they would need the school id and the city id to refer to a particular school.
- It's rare but not unknown for a school to move. Either the school physically relocates or the city redraws its boundaries. This opens up the possibility of collisions -- if, say, school 101 moves to a city that already has a school 101.

So all schools should have a unique id with a FK to the City. Each City should also have a unique id with a FK to State. Or you could put County between City and State.

It doesn't effect your method of "drilling down" to find the schools the user wants to see. You ask for the State and use the answer to find all the cities. You ask for the city and use the answer to find all the schools.